uWSGI and nginx on a flask application while apache2 runs for another instance
I have a flask application server.py on a remote ubuntu server which I would like to deploy with uWSGI and reverse proxy it with nginx. However, I somehow cannot seem to get the configuration right as I also have an apache reverse proxy running to forward requests to another application instance running on the same server.
server.ini file for uWSGI config
[uwsgi]
module = server:app

master = true
processes = 4
enable-threads = true

socket = socket.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

config file for nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <domain-name-for-remote-server>;

    location /form-server {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/kafo/server/server.sock;
    }
}


apache2 config file
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName <domain-name-for-remote-server>
     
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyVia Off
    
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /var/lib/r-cert/live/host:f:<domain-name-for-remote-server>.cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/lib/r-cert/live/host:f:otsvm1.<domain-name-for-remote-server>.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/lib/r-cert/live/host:f:otsvm1.<domain-name-for-remote-server>.chain.pem
     
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
 
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/

    # Configuration for Flask app
    ProxyPass /form-server http://127.0.0.1:5000/form-server
    ProxyPassReverse /form-server http://127.0.0.1:5000/form-server

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <domain-name-for-remote-server>
    Redirect Permanent / https://<domain-name-for-remote-server>/
</VirtualHost>


I get a port already in use conflict with this current configurations while trying to start both nginx and apache2
My idea here was to access the application instance over the URL https://<domain-name-for-remote-server>/ and the flask application over http://<domain-name-for-remote-server>/form-server
Reverse proxying and networking is really new for me and I would really appreciate any help here. Thanks!
